# Are there any introductory video courses about philosophy of language on the internet?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

I want to study the **philosophy of language**. Are there any video courses about philosophy of language on the internet?

Comment: Oh, I totally thought this was a question about *The Philosophy of Language on the Internet*, rather than finding information regarding *The Philosophy of Language* on the internet... I will help format that for you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are: The John Searle Lectures on the Philosphy of Language.

All episodes are uploaded on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uk5pIzCNOzU

Comment: Come to think of it,isn't John Searle a big name in linguistic?